# Loading partials with dust express

Tags: express, dust.js

How can I load a partial view with dust server-side rendering. I have tried

```
{>"../partials/head"/}
```

Which just gets removed from the rendered output.

the view folder structure is like

```
views
    pages
        main.dust
    partials
        head.dust
```

I am using the following package https://github.com/krakenjs/adaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dust doesn't understand filesystem layout-- it is just a string renderer.

If you want Dust to try to load templates from other locations, you should write a **loader** to help. You attach this loader to the hook `dust.onLoad`.

A loader looks like this:

```
dust.onLoad = function(templateName, callback) {
  // do some path calculation maybe
  fs.readFile(templateName + '.js', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function(err, data) {
    callback(err, data); // node-style callback
  });
};
```

When you invoke a partial like `{> "../partials/head" /}`, your function will be invoked with `../partials/head` as the first argument. You can use `path` and `fs` methods to load the correct file and pass it to the callback.

More information: http://www.dustjs.com/guides/onload/